# Disable Logging or Set Log Level Elasticache-Cluster-client

Tags: java, aws-sdk, spymemcached

Could someone let me know how to disable logging or set log level to ERROR for http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/elasticache-java-cluster-client/1.0.61.0

It uses the spymemcached implementation underneath.

```
System.setProperty("net.spy.log.LoggerImpl", "net.spy.memcached.compat.log.SunLogger");
   java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("net.spy.memcached").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE);
```

I am using the above  but i need it using SLF4J